# gspread: Retrieve Filtered Data from GoogleSheets

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread, google-sheets-query

I have a google sheet with a filter/query that only shows the data that verifies the filter's conditions. To retrieve the data for python I use gspread, but hiddenrows are appearing too (as if there was no filter at all).

How can I differentiate the rows selected from the ones who weren't?

I don't understand if this can work without adding more functions to gspread, or if I need to create a new function. If so, what should the function be?

Answer (score 2):

I found that function fetch_sheet_metadata() which is inside class spreadsheet of gspread gives out the filters and hiddenValues for each filter, which is enough to solve my problem.